# How to implement files in the main.cpp file?

Tags: c++

I have a C++ project that I am working on. I have five files that I am working with, they are as follows

```
1. main.cpp
2. Account.h
3. ListDA.h
4. Account.cpp
5. ListDA.cpp
```

I need to implement the files in the `main.cpp` but I am not sure how to exactly do that or which of the files listed I need to do that with. I have code written in each of the files but the code I have in the `main.cpp` is not doing what I am wanting it to do.

I know it's because of the lack of code I have for it to preform but I am not sure how to exactly write the code I need to preform those actions.

I am a little lost. Any advise is helpful. If you need more information to give advise please let me know I will do the best I can. Thanks

I got that issue fixed but when I run the program it is not doing what I want it to do. I thought all the code I need is in the 5 files I have for it. Any help please?

Comment: I am learning c++ at least I am trying. That is why I am trying to get advise on how to do this cause I am a little stuck.

Comment: i can help you on chat if you want

Comment: hm. trying to check if out. click on the chat link and i might see you there

Comment: You should post the code of your `main.cpp` file so we can see what might be going wrong.

Comment: I cant chat on here. It won't let me. got yahoo or something?

Answer (score 1):

if the .cpp files are #include-ing their header file, all you need to do is to include the headerfiles in the main. Is that what you wanted to do?

main:

```
#include List.h 
#include account.h
```

Account.cpp

```
#include account.h
```

Same thing for list.cpp

Comment: When I add them in the main.cpp file it says that there is an error because it was expecting a file name. The Account.h and ListDA.h are already included in their corresponding .cpp files

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your files follow the standard header (.h) and implementation (.cpp) layout, you should just be able to include your header files in your main.cpp.

For example: If I had files Class.h with the class defenition, Class.cpp with the class implementation and main.cpp where I wish to use Class, I would simply add #include "Class.h" to the top of main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Class.h"

int main()
{
    //...Rest of code
    return 0;
}
```

It would be helpful to know what compiler and platform you're using if you need further instructions. (e.g. Visual Studio/gcc, Windows/Linux/Mac, etc.)

Comment: I am using visual studios. When I add them in the main.cpp file it says that there is an error because it was expecting a file name. The Account.h and ListDA.h are already included in their corresponding .cpp files

Comment: Did you remember to add the quotes? Specifically `#include "Account.h"`

Comment: I thought you put < > around it

Comment: Usually, using `#include <filename>` will include a filename that is in the project's include directory, whereas using `#include "filename"` will include files in the same directory/project.

So, in this case you should most likely be using `#include "Account.h"`

Comment: Okay, thank you so much. I have another question if you don't mind

Comment: Without seeing some of the code or you saying more about it it's going to be impossible to answer your second question. Maybe provide some additional info in the question?

Comment: What info would be needed? I will try to provide all that I can.

Comment: What it's supposed to do, what it does/doesn't do, what exactly is in the files you're including, etc. At the moment all we know is that some files exist, as far as we know, they're empty.
It's probably a good idea to move this to a new question, too.

Comment: okay. If I post all the code from all the files that will be a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can put class declarations in a `.h` or `.hpp` file with the same name as the class name and put the definitions in `.cpp` with the same name as the class name. For example in your case assuming you have an `Account` class, put the class declarations in `Account.h` file and the class definition in `Account.cpp` file. `main.cpp` file would be the application code which uses this class.

This link would give a better idea:

http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~hasti/cs368/CppTutorial/NOTES/CLASSES-INTRO.html